# develop oracle sql to build dimension

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]I have three tables in 3rd Normalized form and these tables are populated by java application.

```
MA_COMPANY_PROFILE (table 1)
MA_ACCOUNT (table 2)
SEC_USER (table 3)

Hierarchy is from MA_COMPANY_PROFILE, MA_ACCOUNT, SEC_USER.

relationship between MA_COMPANY_PROFILE and MA_ACCOUT is 1:n
relationship between MA_COMPANY_PROFILE and SEC_USER is n:n
relationship between MA_ACCOUNT and SEC_USER is n:1
```

When we use below sql in informatica to load this data in denormalized format,

```
select *
from 
MA_COMPANY_PROFILE MA_CMY_PRF,
MA_ACCOUNT MA_AC,
ACCOUNT_STATUS AC_ST,
SEC_USER SEC_USR,
SEC_USERS_LASTLOGIN SEC_USR_LL
where 
MA_CMY_PRF.PROFILE_ID=MA_AC.PROFILE_ID(+) and 
MA_CMY_PRF.PROFILE_ID =SEC_USR.PROFILE_ID(+)
```

we get different number of accounts in source table and warehouse table 
or when we try to match number of security users in source and warehouse.

how do we approach this or prepare oracle sql to develop correctly to match source accounts and users and warehouse tables?

Comment: If you have a many to many relationship, you need to resolve it with an intersection entity. I don't think that necessarily solves you problem(s), but that's a start

Comment: This may be stating the obvious but you're linking between 5 tables and only have conditions for 3 of them... as there are no restrictions on AC_ST and SEC_USR_LL you will get cartesian results. (or is there a snippet of the where clause missing?).

Comment: added three tables structure.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking just about the 3 tables concerned and ignore the 2 tables which dont have conditions... you should be flowing from one table to the inter table and from the inter table to the final table, so the final condition would look like

MA_CMY_PRF.PROFILE_ID=MA_AC.PROFILE_ID AND MA_AC.USER_ID = SEC_USR.USER_ID

This assumes that PROFILE_ID is the primary key of MA_COMPANY_PROFILE, USER_ID is the primary key for SEC_USER and that there are foreign keys to both on the MA_ACCOUNT table. Also you've used (+) presumably to ensure that, where no match is found, you always have a record populated with just the info from MA_CMY_PRF and nulls from the related tables, I've left this off as I don't know your requirement.

Comment: I found the reason why the source table count and my target count are mismatch for profile_id, account_id, user_id. Since source tables are having null value in my join column ie profile_id.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the source table count and my target count are mismatch for profile_id, account_id, user_id. Since source tables are having null value in my join column ie profile_id.